# Finding all parent childless records in SQL Server to create a "default value" child

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

First let me get something out of the way: my knowledge of SQL is very, very limited (to understanding basic CRUD operations only, sadly -- talk to me of JOINs and stuff and you might as well be speaking Esperanto). This is something I know I need to and actually am working on, but it's also something that takes time, time I don't currently have to solve this particular problem.

I have a couple of tables, like so:

```
TBL_Cities      TBL_Provinces      TBL_Regions      TBL_Countries
----------      -------------      -----------      -------------
CityID          ProvinceID         RegionID         CountryID
ProvinceID      RegionID           CountryID        CountryCode
CityCode        ProvinceCode       RegionCode       CountryName
CityName        ProvinceName       RegionName
```

As you can probably surmise, yes, the tables are related via a foreign key from `Cities` to `Provinces`, from `Provinces` to `Regions`, and from `Regions` to `Countries` (please do note that the DB design was not of my authoring so I'm just relaying what I have.) Due to this structure, there's a number of provinces that have several cities attached to them, and there's also a number of provinces with *no* cities attached to them.

Because of this design, a person's address is done by linking up from the bottom-most location entity (which, for this particular example, would be Cities). Makes sense so far, right?

**THE QUESTION**: I need to somehow find out the IDs of all the childless `Province` entities, and in the `Cities` table, generate a "default" entry for each of those childless `Provinces`, so that our current address building engine works without having to modify the current database column structure (that is, building a "full" location from the `City` and working our way up to the `Country`). This is... more than just a little bit over my abilities, so here I am requesting help.

I know this is probably too much to ask, but can someone tell me how to go around this, or at the very least point me in the right direction?

Comment: As far as  person's address is linking to city and you probably will never have all cities in your table cities wouldn't an entry `Unknown_InProvince' in your table cities be a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

To find all childless provinces you would use

```
SELECT ProvinceId FROM TBL_Provinces
WHERE ProvinceID NOT IN
(SELECT DISTINCT(ProvinceID) FROM TBL_Cities)
```

To insert default values for each of these provinces

```
INSERT INTO TBL_Cities (ProvinceID, CityCode, CityName)
SELECT ProvinceId, 'DefaultCityCode', 'DefaultCityName' FROM TBL_Provinces
WHERE ProvinceID NOT IN
(SELECT DISTINCT(ProvinceID) FROM TBL_Cities)
```

I am not sure why you would want to add default city names. If a province doesn't have cities it should be fine.

Comment: By "default city name" I meant an entry for each childless province saying "No cities found" or something of the sort, but that at least provides me a valid entry to build the location structure from the `City` going upwards into the `Country`. I'm very sorry for not being clearer in my actual question.

Answer (score 0):

As far as never all cities will be provided and a default city for a Provice will be needed, I would not restrict the addition to the cities and do something like:

```
INSERT INTO TBL_Cities (ProvinceID, CityCode, CityName)
SELECT ProvinceId, '<unknown>', 'DefaultCityName for ' + ProvinceName 
FROM TBL_Provinces
```

to prevent duplicates by running the query more than once you could use

```
INSERT INTO TBL_Cities (ProvinceID, CityCode, CityName)
SELECT ProvinceId, '<unknown>', 'DefaultCityName for ' + ProvinceName 
FROM TBL_Provinces
LEFT JOIN TBL_Cities C on C.CityName='DefaultCityName for ' + ProvinceName 
where C.CityID is NULL
```